# Creating and building a ROS package

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i use ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo, when i try to build the packages in the catkin workspace, it returns:

Base path: /home/mohammad/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/mohammad/catkin_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/mohammad/catkin_ws/build"

[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BodyRequest
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DeleteModel
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ODEJointProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SpawnModel
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetLinkState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetJointProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetWorldProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetJointTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_JointRequest
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ModelState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetModelState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ApplyJointEffort
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WorldState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ContactState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetJointProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ApplyBodyWrench
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetLinkProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LinkStates
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPhysicsProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLinkState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetModelProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LinkState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ContactsState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetModelState
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLinkProperties
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetModelConfiguration
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ODEPhysics
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ModelStates
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetPhysicsProperties
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_FlightAnim
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trims
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_raw_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pressure_raw
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pwm
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_RecordEnable
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_LedAnim
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_euler_angles
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_Navdata
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_raw
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_perf
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector21
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_watchdog
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_of
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix33
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_detect
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_video_stream
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_references
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_zimmu_3000
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_gyros_offsets
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wifi
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_hdvideo_stream
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wind_speed
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_time
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_altitude
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_rc_references
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_phys_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector31
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_magneto
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_games
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_adc_data_frame
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_demo
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_kalman_pressure
[  0%] [  0%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'ardronelib'
Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_CamSelect
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
Cloning into 'ardronelib'...
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trackers_send
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
Built target gazebo_ros_gencfg
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_filter_state
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_SetMaxControl
Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_SetReference
[  0%] Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_SetStayWithinDistance
[  1%] Built target tum_ardrone_gencfg
[  1%] [  1%] Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_SetInitialReachDistance
Built target _tum_ardrone_generate_messages_check_deps_SetStayTime
[  3%] Built target thirdparty
[  3%] [  3%] Built target driver_base_generate_messages_cpp
Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  3%] Built target MultiCameraPlugin
[  3%] Built target polled_camera_generate_messages_cpp
[  3%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  3%] [  3%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  3%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
Built target polled_camera_generate_messages_lisp
[  3%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[  3%] [  3%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[  3%] [  3%] [  3%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
Built target polled_camera_generate_messages_py
[  3%] [  3%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target bond_generate_messages_py
[  3%] Built target driver_base_generate_messages_lisp
[  3%] [  3%] [  3%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target driver_base_generate_messages_py
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  3%] Built target gazebo_ros_block_laser
[  3%] [  3%] Built target gazebo_ros_utils
Built target gazebo_ros_f3d
[  3%] Built target gazebo_ros_force
[  3%] Built target gazebo_ros_gpu_laser
[  4%] Built target gazebo_ros_ft_sensor
[  5%] Built target gazebo_ros_hand_of_god
[  5%] Built target gazebo_ros_imu
[  5%] Built target gazebo_ros_laser
[  5%] Built target gazebo_ros_p3d
[  6%] Built target gazebo_ros_planar_move
[  6%] Built target gazebo_ros_projector
[  7%] Built target gazebo_ros_range
[  7%] Built target gazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive
[  7%] [  7%] [  8%] Built target gazebo_ros_template
Built target gazebo_ros_video
Built target gazebo_ros_tricycle_drive
[ 17%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 17%] Built target default_robot_hw_sim
[ 17%] Built target gazebo_ros_control
[ 26%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 35%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 46%] Built target ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_lisp
[ 59%] Built target ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_py
[ 70%] Built target ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_cpp
[ 70%] Built target gazebo_ros_paths_plugin
[ 71%] Built target gazebo_ros_api_plugin
[ 75%] [ 75%] Built target tum_ardrone_generate_messages_py
Built target tum_ardrone_generate_messages_cpp
[ 77%] Built target tum_ardrone_generate_messages_lisp
[ 78%] Built target gazebo_plugins_gencfg
[ 78%] Built target gazebo_ros_bumper
[ 78%] Built target gazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory
[ 79%] Built target gazebo_ros_diff_drive
[ 80%] Built target gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher
[ 80%] Built target hokuyo_node
[ 80%] Built target gazebo_ros_joint_trajectory
[ 80%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages
[ 80%] Built target pub_joint_trajectory_test
[ 80%] Built target ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages
[ 80%] [ 80%] Built target ardrone_autonomy_gencpp
Built target tum_ardrone_gencpp
[ 80%] Built target tum_ardrone_generate_messages
[ 81%] Built target vision_reconfigure
[ 83%] Built target drone_autopilot
[ 83%] Built target gazebo_ros_camera_utils
[ 84%] Built target camera_synchronizer
[ 87%] Built target drone_gui
Linking CXX executable /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tum_ardrone/drone_stateestimation
[ 88%] Built target gazebo_ros_camera
[ 88%] Built target gazebo_ros_depth_camera
[ 88%] Built target gazebo_ros_multicamera
[ 89%] Built target gazebo_ros_openni_kinect
[ 89%] Built target gazebo_ros_prosilica
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/mohammad/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tum_ardrone/drone_stateestimation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tum_ardrone/CMakeFiles/drone_stateestimation.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out
github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection timed out

Cloning into 'ardronelib'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection timed out
github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out

Cloning into 'ardronelib'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection timed out
github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out

-- Had to git clone more than once:
3 times.
CMake Error at /home/mohammad/catkin_ws/devel/tmp/ardronelib-gitclone.cmake:40 (message):
Failed to clone repository: 'git://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardronelib.git'

make[2]: *** [/home/mohammad/catkin_ws/devel/src/ardronelib-stamp/ardronelib-download] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
.
.
.
someone knows something about it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268703/creating-and-building-a-ros-package/) by [mt.tofigh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31568/mt.tofigh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-13**:
You should remove all the lines that end in `Built target`, people will have an easier time seeing the errors.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-13**:
Using pre-formatted text (the `101010` button) would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you need a version of glut (freeglut3-dev?), libblas-dev, and liblapack-dev:

```
cannot find -lglut /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
```

Beyond that:

```
Error 1 make[1]: [tum_ardrone/CMakeFiles/drone_stateestimation.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: * * Waiting for unfinished jobs.... fatal: unable to connect to github.com : github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Can you ping github.com from your build computer?

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0